# cmd.exe stays open after start command opeing multiple files

Tags: excel, windows, batch-file, cmd

I already googled and tried several solutions but without success...

My batch script looks the following, it opens four files but then cmd.exe window stays open and cannot be closed anymore. Even Task Manager asks for admin rights if I want to close. I am no admin, only normal user, so to force closing the cmd window I can only logoff and re-login to windows.
I already tried several options ("/b" option on start command, "exit" command at the end, also "exit 0" ... without any difference)

```
start "" /b "file1.xlsx"
@ping -n 3 localhost> nul
start "" /b "file2.xlsx"
@ping -n 1 localhost> nul
start "" /b "file3.xlsx"
@ping -n 1 localhost> nul
start "" /b "file4.xlsx"
```

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2.

Comment: Why not open Excel instead of using whichever file is currently registered to open files with an `xlsx` extension? example: ```@For %%G In ("file1" "file2" "file3" "file4") Do @Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office 16\ClientX64\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "%%~G.xlsx" 2>NUL && %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2```

Comment: @Compo Hardcoding the version? :( It is probably in AppPaths so you can just `start excel.exe ...` ? And what about OpenOffice? I don't like your idea at all...

Comment: why `@ping -n 3 localhost` instead of `timeout 2`?

Comment: @Compo thank you, but hmm, I also don't like the idea of hardcoding the Excel version. Some of my colleagues will use it as well. I have no clue what kind of app they are using and in which path it is installed

Comment: @phuclv thanks for the hint, I guess it will not change the behaviour

Comment: xtoff and @Anders, my comment said **example**. If the end user can be certain that the application they wish to open `.xlsx` files **is** registered to that extension, then they are free not to use my more robust code! ```@For %%G In ("file1" "file2" "file3" "file4") Do @Start "" "EXCEL.EXE" "%%~G.xlsx" 2>NUL && %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2```. The point of my example was to show that they're `Start`ing an executable program with a file argument.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom add:
:end
exit

Then most probably you can solve this

Comment: Thank you - to jump to `:END` I will also have to define something like `IF bla GOTO :END` , but why?

Comment: Answer requires code example. Also this answer will look better with use of markdown rules  - stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

@phuclv Thank you! I changed the pause from ping command to timeout command as you proposed: and this solved the problem for me.

Great! Thank you!

```
start "" /b "file1.xlsx"
timeout 2
start "" /b "file2.xlsx"
timeout 1
start "" /b "file3.xlsx"
timeout 1
start "" /b "file4.xlsx"
```

Comment: Having a timeout in the first place is a indicator that something is not quite right.